# Save a file and make the console not to close: Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am new to C++ and I am using the free version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

I have written a small code which I use to integrate some differential equations (by using `odeint` libraries provided by `Boost`).

After the integration process ends, the time evolutions of the state variables are stored in the matrix `mat` (I use the **Eigen** libraries to define it row by row):

```
MatrixXd mat(t,4);

for (int i = 0; i <= t-1; i++)
{ 
   mat.row(i) << times[i], x_vec[i][0], x_vec[i][1], x_vec[i][2] ;
};
```

Then I save the content of the matrix in a .txt file:

```
ofstream file("mat_save.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{ file << mat << '\n'; }
file.close();
```

However the .txt file is created only if I run the code in **Debug** mode, while if I only **compile** it the file is no longer created and no output can be displayed in the Console, since it is only opened when Debug mode is chosen.

Is there a way to make the Console appear and remain open and also to make the .txt file to be successfully saved, simply "compiling" the code avoiding debugging?

If so, I would save lot of time because the debugging is quite slow.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Switch to release mode and run it? It should look similar to the debug mode, only faster and with very little debugging support.

Comment: Do you now what compiling means?

Comment: I second the recommendation to switch to release mode. However make sure you use the release mode libraries and not the debug ones.

Comment: Note that when you run from the IDE your program's working directory is by default the folder containing the project file. This is the same in release and debug mode. When you click on an executable in the OS file explorer the working directory is the one containing the executable. The working directory is the default folder where your files will be read / written if you don't specify a path.

Comment: ***However the .txt file is created only if I run the code in Debug mode, while if I only compile it the file is no longer created and no output can be displayed in the Console, since it is only opened when Debug mode is chosen.*** Compiling does not run the program. It if successful creates your runnable application in a console application project. You can run it in the debugger or by using file explorer. Note that debug mode can be 100 times slower at running your code than release mode so you may want to spend time to setup release mode.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX actually I am not so sure. I started using C++ a month ago, so I am a bit confused. Practically speaking, in VS I compile using CTRL+F7, while I debug using F5.

Comment: Thanks to @drescherjm, I have learnt that compiling the .cpp file, the "only" thing that happens is that a .exe file with the same name of the .cpp one is created; when I start the Debug, the .exe file is executed and so the Console is opened and the required .txt file created.

Comment: Running the .exe in Release mode actually works fine, but only after adding the proper libraries. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if by debug you mean running the code in Visual Studio vs compiling and then running the created exe. It Kind of sounds like a relative path issue.

Try using a full path. Or try opening a command prompt, **cd**ing to the path with the exe and then running it and check to see if the file is created in the folder you **cd**ed to.

You can also try opening the exe in Visual Studio like it was a project. Another thing to try is attaching VS to a running process to debug: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

The Windows Powertool "Handle" can display what handles a process is currently using which could be useful in determining if it is writing a file somewhere unexpected: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Comment: Thank you for answering, @ramonecung. The straightest way to solve my problem is to run the executable file in release mode after adding the proper libraries paths. Moreover, I will surely investigate the further information you gave me.